# Нужна помощь с авторизацией на сайте

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, авторизация

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте (https://onlinecontract.ru). Нашел статейку на английском (https://betterprogramming.pub/web-scraping-behind-authentication-with-python-be5f82eb85f0), где по-шагово объяснены все действия.
Однако при запуске программы выдает множество ошибок следущего вида:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 428, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='onlinecontract.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /otp/index.phtml (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\company\Authorization.py", line 30, in <module>
    response = rqs.post('https://onlinecontract.ru/otp/index.phtml', headers=headers, data=data)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='onlinecontract.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /otp/index.phtml (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Не понимаю в чем ошибка и что мне делать дальше.

Мой код выглядит следующим образом:

```
import requests as rqs

headers = {
    'authority': 'onlinecontract.ru',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'origin': 'https://onlinecontract.ru',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'referer': 'https://onlinecontract.ru/otp/signin',
    'accept-language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'cookie': 'lastEvent_16984=%7B%22evn%22%3A5464%7D; tmr_lvid=e13b8ad4b794abc5f65e76aa8b0cdb7b; tmr_lvidTS=1618855683566; _ym_uid=1618855684420902237; _ym_d=1618855684; _ga=GA1.2.846082366.1618855684; _gid=GA1.2.1416083211.1618855684; otpClient=visit+otp; notification_supplier_profile_16984=2; _ym_isad=1; _sp_ses.53a1=*; tmr_detect=1%7C1618999187131; _gat_gtag_UA_49471738_1=1; _ym_visorc=w; _sp_id.53a1=7b14a34f-100b-497f-8baf-afa51ee7756f.1618855684.8.1618999219.1618946697.627abf84-84a3-4eca-9d76-337bbad98206; tmr_reqNum=93',
}

data = {
    'Login': 'login',
    'Pass': 'password',
    'go': '',
    'profile_page': '',
    'options': ''
}

url = 'https://onlinecontract.ru/otp/index.phtml'

s = rqs.session()

response = rqs.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код, который вызывает ошибку...

Comment: в 'Login': 'login' и 'Pass': 'password' - реальные логин и пароль?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='onlinecontract.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /otp/index.phtml (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

Ошибка намекает на неудачную проверку сертификата.
Добавьте `verify=False` в `rqs.post()` для отключения проверки.
Должно быть так:

```
response = rqs.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
```

В итоге:

```
>>> response.status_code
200
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Получилось.